# R: abind matrix of lists

Tags: r, data-structures, data-analysis

The following small snippet for binding a matrix of lists doesn't work:

```
library(abind)

 my_list <- list(c(1, 2), c(1, 2, 3))
 my_matrix <- rbind(my_list, my_list)
 abind(my_matrix, my_matrix)
```

This is not obvious, because using it abind treats matrices differently:
If it encounters a regular matrix like

```
my_simple_matrix = matrix(nrow=2, ncol=2)
abind(my_simple_matrix, my_simple_matrix)
```

will work.

Comment: `Error in abind(my_matrix, my_matrix) : could not find function "abind"`. Note that when using a non base R function, you should start the script with a call to `library()`. I will edit the question.

Comment: So what is your expected output? Do you want to column-bind or row-bind? I'm not familiar with `abind` but you could use `dplyr::bind_cols(as.tibble(my_matrix), as.tibble(my_matrix))` or `dplyr::bind_rows(as.tibble(my_matrix), as.tibble(my_matrix))`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answers and sorry for having forgotten to mention that the `abind` function comes from the frequently used `abind` package. My desired output would be to row-bind.